# when using Actions.reset("key") in react-native-router-flux, what will affect the component

Tags: react-native, router, react-native-router-flux

I use react-native-router-flux as the react-native router, In my situation, when the user login out, I use Action.reset("key"), but the `getDerivedStateFromProps` `next props` still have pre-data, can anyone tell me the reason, or how to solve the problem using the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the react-native-router-flux is based on react-navigaion. so we can find the concepte and explanation.

firstly we see the source js code,it is located in navigationStore

```
reset = (routeName, data) => {
    const params = filterParam(data);
    const parent = getParent(this.state, routeName);
    this.dispatch(
      StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: parent ? parent.key : null,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
          }),
        ],
      }),
    );
  };
}
```

The `StackActions.reset` only reset action wipes the whole navigation state and replaces it with the result of several actions. so it only change the navigation state. we can see this in react-navigation [api](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset).

and for the navigation lifecyle, unlike the web, the navigation is not remount the compoent. it manager the router use stack. the following is the offical says:

```
Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.

When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.
```

so the navigation will unmount the component when the component is removed from the router stack, like back, reset

Comment: I debug my app, when reset, the component is re-created and mount